# How to have responsive text and divs side by side

Tags: html, css

I'd like to have in a single line text and 3 divs, in the second line another text and three more divs etc.
Currently that's how it looks like
[image]
and my code is

```
svg {
    margin-left: 0%;
    float: left;
    height: 12%;
    width: 28%;
}
h2{
  left: 2%;
  font-size: 2em;
  padding-top: 180px;
  top: -40px;
}
```

I cannot use class names because each div has a different one, that gets dynamically, and there are more than thirty divs. That's why I'm trying to fix it by using the h2 and div as elements.

I managed with this code

```
div {
        margin-left: 10px;
        float: right;
        bottom: 1852px;
        position: relative;
        height: 12%;
        width: 28%;
    }
    h2{
      left: 2%;
      position: relative;
      font-size: 2em;
      padding-top: 180px;
      top: -40px;
    }
```

to achieve what I'm trying

[image]
but it is different in different screens. Sometimes display 4 divs and other times 2 divs. I tried position: fixed but couldn't make it. I'm not familiar with css and I'm really struggling on this.

Comment: Can we see the HTML and CSS code you've used?

Answer (score 0):

Create divs with [percentage](https://jsfiddle.net/rflfn/6rvsrcy8/).
Or you can use [calc()](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_calc.asp) for calculate margins for box.

```
.box-container {
  border: 1px solid #500;
}
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
}
.box-text {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 40%;
}
.content {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.inner {
   margin: 10px;
   padding: 10px;
   background-color: #CCC;
}
```

Other solution is [create another](https://jsfiddle.net/rflfn/6rvsrcy8/1/) div inside div box and add margins.

Comment: thank you for your answer but it shows all the divs inline and I want three in each line. Texts became as a table with 2 columns and four rows. It's not what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/rflfn/6rvsrcy8/2/ without divs rows? you can post your code?

Comment: Your answer is correct but each of my divs has a different class name which gets dynamically that's why i cannot declare more than 30 class names. I'm trying to find a solution by using div and h2.

Comment: I think I do not understand it yet... but see if this help https://jsfiddle.net/rflfn/6rvsrcy8/3/, you dont need class name, use a container and element names.

Comment: That would be a great answer @rflfn if there wasn't a container. I cannot include all of my js into a single container. I tried to use the body element instead of container but couldn't fix it. font-size: 0; in body is also another problem for me

Comment: elements with inline-block properties have 3px of spaces, you need font-size:0 to remove, but if you divs have no space between them, then you do not need this property. If you remove font-size:0 you layout broken?

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:table`, `display:table-row` and `display:table-cell` combination as follows and keep elements perfectly in place.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%; /* just in case you want it to span whole height */
  margin: 0; /* otherwise dont use this */
  padding: 0;
}
div.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; /* just in case you want it to span whole height */
  /* otherwise use a custom height */
}
div.table-row {
  display: table-row;
}
.table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 10px; /* creating gaps */
  vertical-align: middle; /* aligning to middle */
}
div.table-cell {
  width:25%; /* width of the content parent */
}
div.content {
  background-color: grey;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="table-row">
    <h2 class="table-cell">text 1</h2>
    <div class="table-cell"><div class="content"></div></div>
    <div class="table-cell"><div class="content"></div></div>
    <div class="table-cell"><div class="content"></div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-row">
    <h2 class="table-cell">text 2</h2>
    <div class="table-cell"><div class="content"></div></div>
    <div class="table-cell"><div class="content"></div></div>
    <div class="table-cell"><div class="content"></div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-row">
    <h2 class="table-cell">text 3</h2>
    <div class="table-cell"><div class="content"></div></div>
    <div class="table-cell"><div class="content"></div></div>
    <div class="table-cell"><div class="content"></div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```